# Spring: how to get the app's directory path during a bean construction time?

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a bean as follows:

```
<bean id="myBean" class="MyBeanClass">
    <constructor-arg value="\WEB-INF\myfile.dat"/>
</bean>
```

In the bean's contructor, I need to build the file's full path. To do that, I have to first find the app's root path first.

Thanks and regards.

**Update**

Per Michael-O's suggestion, here is my solution (so easy).

Spring bean:

```
<bean id="myBean" class="MyBeanClass">
    <constructor-arg value="/myfile.dat"/> <!--under WEB-INF/classes-->
</bean>
```

Java:

```
public MyBeanClass(String path) throws Exception {
    ClassPathResource file  = new ClassPathResource(path);
    lookup = new LookupService(file.getFile().getPath(), LookupService.GEOIP_MEMORY_CACHE);
}
```

Michael, thanks!!!

Comment: Did you try using `System.getProperty("user.dir")` ?

Comment: Vimsha, this is an interesting solution. Does it work in any circumstances (web, non-web, platform-independent)?

Comment: Vimsha, I notice a difference between your solution and my question. System.getProperty("user.dir") gives the directory containing the app, not the app's directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Spring's [`Resource`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.5/reference/resources.html) class in your bean and spring will do the rest for you.

After seeing @curious1's edit, there is a better solution to his answer. Please do not use that. Go with this one:

`beans.xml`:

```
<!-- START: Improvement 2 -->
<context:annotation-config />
<bean id="service" class="LookupService">
    <constructor-arg value="classpath:/myfile.dat"/> <!--under WEB-INF/classes-->
    <constructor-arg>
         <util:constant static-field="LookupService.GEOIP_MEMORY_CACHE"/>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
<!-- END: Improvement 2 -->
<!-- Spring autowires here -->
<bean id="myBean" class="MyBeanClass" />

<!-- START: Improvement 1 -->
<bean id="myBean" class="MyBeanClass" />
    <constructor-arg value="classpath:/myfile.dat"/> <!--under WEB-INF/classes-->
</bean>
<!-- END: Improvement 1 -->
```

Java:

```
public MyBeanClass(Resource path) throws Exception {
    lookup = new LookupService(path.getInputStream(), LookupService.GEOIP_MEMORY_CACHE);
}
```

This is source-agnostic, does not rely on files **and** is the Spring way.

Edit 2: Rethinking my code, it can be even better:

```
public class MyBeanClass {
    @Autowired
    LookupService service;
}
```

and configure `LookupService` in your `beans.xml`.

Comment: Michael, LookupService(path.getInputStream(), LookupService.GEOIP_MEMORY_CACHE);
} has compilation error. Should use: path.getFile().getPath() ?

Comment: @curious1, yes, that is correct. You would need to change the signature of the `LookupService`. You can call `getFile()...` but remember, `InputStream` abstract of the actual localtion. In a webapp, you are not guaranteed to receive a `File`. `InputStream` is a safe bet. See my edit.

Comment: @curious1, welcome. The Spring Manual is a really good insight how to decouple stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should consider using:

`getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream()`

inside constructor. This will use your classpath, so you "WEB-INF\myfile.dat", will be visible. Next think is use resource directory to put all resources in one directory (default: under root directory in WAR file)

Comment: There is a better way.